# Lua Table is nil

Tags: arrays, lua, null

For some reason Lua tells me that this line makes an error:

```
for i=1, #set do
```

Where set is a 2-dimensional table parameter of a function I made.
It gives me an error:

> Attempt to get length of a nil value (local set)

The weird thing is, that I run this function more than 1000 times but the error shows up only once. I'm not really sure why.
Any help would be appreciated. And also I can print values from set and they will show up, I think this is a possible bug.

Edit: this is the function: (or the important part of it)

```
function GeneticTrainer:evaluate(id,correct,set)
local returny=0
local net=self.Networks[id]
for i=1, #set do
    --   print(i..k[i])
    net:Update(set[i])

    local error= math.abs(correct[i]-net.output[1])
    returny = returny + (1-(error/10))
end
```

And this is where I call it:

```
function GeneticTrainer:Evolve(Problem,Set)
local A=math.random(1,self.Population)
local B=math.random(1,self.Population)
if A==B then
    B=math.random(1,self.Population)
end
local AFitness = self:evaluate(A,Problem,Set)
local BFitness = self:evaluate(B,Problem,Set)
```

And this is where I call it:

```
BinarySet={{0,0},{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}}
```

`for i=1, iterations do
GATrainer:Evolve(Target,BinarySet) end`

Comment: Apparently, `set` was `nil`. It's impossible to know why that happened if you don't post the relevant code, preferably as a [MCVE].

Comment: Does your `net:Update` modify `set` in anyway or change the item count while it's still iterating through the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
function GeneticTrainer:evaluate(id,correct,set)
  local returny=0
  local net=self.Networks[id]
  for i=1, #set do  -- this line causes the error!
  -- an so on...
```

The error is caused in the above code segment, line 4. As there is obviously no asigment to `set` between the function header and `#set`, `set` must enter the function as `nil`

So next you check where you call `GeneticTrainer:evaluate(id,correct,set)`
which happens to be this:

```
function GeneticTrainer:Evolve(Problem,Set)
  local A=math.random(1,self.Population)
  local B=math.random(1,self.Population)
  if A==B then
    B=math.random(1,self.Population)
  end
  local AFitness = self:evaluate(A,Problem,Set)
  local BFitness = self:evaluate(B,Problem,Set)
```

As there is obviously no change to Set, which enters the function `GeneticTrainer:Evolve(Problem,Set)` and then `self:evaluate(B,Problem,Set)` as well the nil value must originate outside this function as well.

Further code is not provided.
That you call a function a 1000 times without errors does not mean that it cannot cause an error if you call it with different parameters the 1001st time.

Just follow `set` through the call stack and you will find the problem.

You should have a stack traceback provided with your error message which tells you in which line you call each function.

This is very simple and you will have to do this or similar a million times as a programmer. You don't need us to help you here.

Edit:

Afer your comments I reduced your code to a minimum (something you should have done for your question) and ran it through the Lua online demo with no issues at all. https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

I also tested it with another Lua interpreter using 5000 iterations with no issues.

```
function eval(id,correct,set)
  print(#set)
end

function evolve(Problem,Set)
  local AFitness = eval(A,Problem,Set)
  local BFitness = eval(B,Problem,Set)
end

  BinarySet={{0,0},{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}}
for i=1, 10 do
  evolve(Target,BinarySet) 
end
```

I'd say it is pretty impossible that a recent Lua built has a bug that makes tables disappear. Please check your code again.

Comment: Well but set isn't nil because I can print values from it I can say "print(set[1][1]) and it does print. Is this a bug maybe?

Comment: did you print that right befor the line that causes the error?.. nil is nil. A table doen't just disappear.
Maybe a typo? Set vs set somewhere?

Comment: Yes! I made a print exactly before it and it prints out fine then causes an error

Comment: I edited my answer due to your comments. For me it works fine. A bug like that is very very unlikely. Upload your script somewhere or use a page like www.pastebucket.com to share. Maybe you're missing something...